# VBA: Copying Cell Values at Specific Time

Tags: vba, excel

I have contents in column K that is constantly updating throughout the day. I want to copy the values of specific cells at specific times, and paste them into column F. What I lack is the VBA code to copy the contents at a specific time.

Comment: Have a look at `Application.OnTime`.  If you get stuck feel free to come back and ask a _real_ question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on chris neilsen's comment (I was not aware of Application.OnTime).

You can do the following (the code below goes in the ThisWorkbook module):

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call ScheduleTask
End Sub


Public Sub ScheduleTask()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:00:00"), "ThisWorkbook.Execute"
End Sub

Public Sub Execute()
    Debug.Print "Executing task", Now

    'Place your code here

    Call ScheduleTask
End Sub
```